# Getting a value error on this question, not entirely sure why

Tags: python, pandas

```
import libraries
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

df = pd.read_csv('https://tf-assets-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/tf-curric/data-analytics-bootcamp/medicalcosts.csv')
```

create two separate DataFrames for sex

```
df_male = df.loc[df['sex'] == 'male']
df_female = df.loc[df['sex'] == 'female']
```

Run a t-test comparing the charges column between males and females and print the results

```
tc, pc = stats.pearsonr(df_male.charges, df_female.charges)
print(tc)
print(pc)
```

Run a t-test comparing the bmi column between males and females and print the results

```
tb, pb = stats.pearsonr(df_male.bmi, df_female.bmi)
print(tb)
print(tb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For pearson correlation you are looking at association between two variables. This means the variables will be of the same length and `stats.pearsonr` expects the two inputs to have the same length.

In your example, you are trying to do correlation between different observations which doesn't quite make sense. Therefore it throws an error:

```
len(df_male.charges)
676

len(df_female.charges)
662
```

For t test, it will work:

```
ttest_ind(df_male.bmi, df_female.bmi)
Ttest_indResult(statistic=1.696752635752224, pvalue=0.08997637178984932)
```

Comment: I realized I didn't read it close enough, the previous question was utilizing a pearsonr. Appreciate the answer though.